# Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive

Tags: javascript, html

I'm getting this error `Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive.` in Chrome mobile browser when I try to click on links that are within an area being affected by the onepageascroll code pasted below.

The code works fine on desktop/full browser size and i'm able to click links.

Once looking at the site on mobile the links become unclickable.

I have searched for the error and found that it has "something" to do with telling preventDefault to not be passive and so I added `e.preventDefault(), { passive: false };` to the touch event under the //bind touch line.

This worked to make links clickable again but broke the functionality of the onepage scroll stuff, so the page no longer moved.

So I'm guessing what I need to know is how to separate the "click" stuff from the "scroll" stuff...

Have included the js code that I have been using

```
 * onepagescroll.js v1.0.0
 * Athuor : Mystika
 * Fork this script on github https://github.com/mystika/onepagescroll
 * http://mystika.me

function onepagescroll(selector, options) {
    var pages = [];
    var currentPage = 1;
    var isPageChanging = false;
    var keyUp = {38:1,33:1};
    var keyDown = {40:1,34:1};
    
    var def = {
        pageContainer: 'li',
        animationType: 'ease-in-out',
        animationTime: 500,
        infinite: true,
        pagination: true,
        keyboard: true,
        direction: 'vertical',
    };

    var setting = extend({},def,options);

    /* initialization */
    function init(){

        window.addEventListener('wheel',onScrollEventHandler);

        css(document.querySelector(selector),{
            transition: 'transform ' + setting.animationTime + 'ms ' + setting.animationType
        });
        
        //allow keyboard input
        if(setting.keyboard){
            addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
                if(keyUp[e.keyCode])
                    changePage(1,pages.length,-1);
                else if(keyDown[e.keyCode])
                    changePage(pages.length,1,1);
            });
        }

        document.querySelector(selector).classList.add('ops-container');
        
        detectTransitionEnd() && document.querySelector(selector).addEventListener(detectTransitionEnd(), function(){
            isPageChanging = false;
        });

        var bullet_list_container = null;
        /* create navigation bullets */
        if(setting.pagination){
            bullet_list_container = document.createElement("ul");
            bullet_list_container.classList.add('ops-navigation');
        }
        
        var index=1;
        [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(selector + ' > ' + setting.pageContainer), function(obj){
            if(setting.pagination){
                var bullet_list = document.createElement('li');
                var bullet = document.createElement('a');
                bullet.setAttribute('data-targetindex',index);
                bullet.href='#';
                bullet_list.appendChild(bullet);
                bullet_list_container.appendChild(bullet_list); 
            }

            obj.classList.add('ops-page');
            
            if(setting.direction == 'horizontal'){
                css(obj,{
                    left:(index-1)*100 + '%',
                    position:'absolute'
                });
            }

            pages.push(obj);
            obj.setAttribute('data-pageindex',index++);
        });

        if(setting.pagination){
            document.body.appendChild(bullet_list_container);
            document.querySelector('a[data-targetindex="' + currentPage +'"]').classList.add('active');
        }

        
    }

    /* wheel event handler */
    function onScrollEventHandler(e){
        if(e.wheelDelta > 0)
            changePage(1,pages.length,-1);
        else
            changePage(pages.length,1,1);
    }

    /* dected transitions completion for block duplicated scrolling */
    function detectTransitionEnd(){
        var t;
        var el = document.createElement('fakeelement');
        var transitions = {
          'transition':'transitionend',
          'OTransition':'oTransitionEnd',
          'MozTransition':'transitionend',
          'WebkitTransition':'webkitTransitionEnd'
        }

        for(t in transitions)
            if( el.style[t] !== undefined )
                return transitions[t];
        return true;
    }


    /* css setter */
    function css(obj,styles){
        for (var _style in styles)
            if(obj.style[_style] !== undefined)
                obj.style[_style] = styles[_style];
        
    }

    /* extend function for user customization */
    function extend(){
        for(var i=1; i<arguments.length; i++)
            for(var key in arguments[i])
                if(arguments[i].hasOwnProperty(key))
                    arguments[0][key] = arguments[i][key];
        return arguments[0];
    }

    //function for page transition
    function changePage(compare,edge,increase){
        if(isPageChanging) return;

        if(currentPage==compare){
            if(setting.infinite)
                currentPage = edge;
            else
                return;
        }
        else{
            currentPage+=increase;
        }

        if(setting.animationTime) isPageChanging = true;
    
        if(setting.pagination){
            document.querySelector('a.active[data-targetindex]').classList.remove('active');
            document.querySelector('a[data-targetindex="' + currentPage +'"]').classList.add('active');
        }
        if(setting.direction == 'vertical'){
            css(document.querySelector(selector),{
                transform:'translate3d(0,' + -(currentPage-1)*100 + '%,0)'
            });
        }
        else if(setting.direction == 'horizontal'){
            css(document.querySelector(selector),{
                transform:'translate3d(' + -(currentPage-1)*100 + '%,0,0)'
            }); 
        }
    }

    /* swipe */
    var fpos = 0;
    var lpos = 0;
    var _n = 90;

    //bind touch
    document.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (e.type == 'touchstart' || e.type == 'touchmove' || e.type == 'touchend' || e.type == 'touchcancel') {
        var touch = e.touches[0] || e.changedTouches[0];
            if(setting.direction == 'vertical')
                fpos = touch.pageY;
            else if(setting.direction == 'horizontal')
                fpos = touch.pageX;
        }
    });
    

    document.addEventListener('touchend', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (e.type == 'touchstart' || e.type == 'touchmove' || e.type == 'touchend' || e.type == 'touchcancel') {
            var touch = e.touches[0] || e.changedTouches[0];
            if(setting.direction == 'vertical')
                lpos = touch.pageY;
            else if(setting.direction == 'horizontal')
                lpos = touch.pageX;
        }
        if(fpos + _n < lpos)
            changePage(1,pages.length,-1);
        else if(fpos > lpos + _n)
            changePage(pages.length,1,1);
    });


    /* check documents ready statement and do init() */
    if(document.readyState === 'complete')
        init();
    else
        window.addEventListener('onload', init(), false);
    
}
```

Comment: The `{ passive: true }` needs to be done when the event listener is added. *edit* and I don't see that anywhere in the code posted

Comment: I had it like this 

`document.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(), {passive: true} ;`

but this was stopping the scrolling from working

Comment: Yes that's the whole point of that "passive" flag. By using it, you're telling the browser that your event handler will allow the default operation to proceed; in other words, that you don't need to `.preventDefault()`.

Comment: Thank you, this is the bit I don't understand though, how would I preserve that scrolling? but also allow the clicks to get through?

I also don't understand why this issue only affects my mobile browsing

Comment: .... I guess I just need clicks to keep on "allowing default" somehow

Comment: The entire point of a "passive" event handler is to allow the browser to keep scrolling even while JavaScript code is running. The idea is that the browser can know for sure that it can scroll and not have to "undo" any position changes if the event handler decides to call `.preventDefault()` later. You're basically telling the browser "I promise not to call `.preventDefault()`. If you want to prevent the default, therefore, don't use a passive event handler.